# Adding a class to a node for a certain term

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I am working on a node content type that has the vocabulary fruits (I love fruits). Per node there are more type of fruits possible. By selecting field tags (terms of the vocabulary) the classes are added to a variable which is printed in the twig template.

Currently this is my code:

```
function theme_preprocess_node__fruit(&$variables) {

    if ($variables['elements']['field_tags'][0]['#title']=== 'Apple') {
        $variables['APPLE'] = 'active';
    }
    if ($variables['elements']['field_tags'][1]['#title']=== 'Banana') {
        $variables['BANANA'] = 'active';
    }
    if ($variables['elements']['field_tags'][2]['#title']=== 'Peer') {
        $variables['PEER'] = 'active';
    }
}
```

My problem is the following the bold number printed between field tags and title: ['field_tags']**[2]**['#title'] . The numbers are the weights of the terms. And when the user deselects one of the terms, the classes will not be printed because the order (weight) is changed. Is there a way to not take into account the weight? (Which is not important for me anyway in this case)

Thanks in advance!:)

Comment: What do you mean by "disregard"?  Should the weight be invisible?  Should the value of the weight not be taken into account?

Comment: Hi, the value should not be taken into account. I have edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function theme_preprocess_node__fruit(&$variables) {

$fieldtag = $variables['elements']['field_tags'];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($fieldtag); $i++) {
    if ($fieldtag[$i]['#title'] === 'Apple') {
        $variables['APPLE'] = 'active';
    }
    if ($fieldtag[$i]['#title'] === 'Banana') {
        $variables['BANANA'] = 'active';
    }
    if ($fieldtag[$i]['#title'] === 'Peer') {
        $variables['PEER'] = 'active';
    }

   }
}
```

Solved it this way, I am looping over the weights and comparing the title every time to the fruit type. Is there a more performant efficient way? Because I want to make a really long list with 200 items...